# c shell script explain

Tags: csh

I am completely new to scripting. Can someone please explain to me what's going on here? Thank you.

```
echo 'Report 1' > ${TMP}/reports.tmp
uuencode ${DATA}/${ext1} ${ext1} >> ${TMP}/reports.tmp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TMP`, `DATA` and `ext1` are variables whose content can be accessed by `$TMP`, `$DATA` and `$ext1` or `${TMP}`, `${DATA}` and `${ext1}`

`echo` is a command to print a string to `standard output`

`uuencode` is a program to encode a binary file into an ASCII representation (might be e.g. needed to transfer the content of a binary file via mail)

`>` means redirection of standard output into a file (*overwriting* the file)

`>>` means redirection of standard output into a file (*appending* to that file)

`echo 'Report 1' > ${TMP}/reports.tmp` creates the file `reports.tmp` in a directory specified by variable `TMP` and writes the string `"Report 1"` into it

`uuencode ${DATA}/${ext1} ${ext1} >> ${TMP}/reports.tmp` appends the uuencoded version of the file `${DATA}/${ext1}` (i.e. directory specified by variable `DATA`, filename specified by `ext1`) to reports.tmp

Comment: thanx for your help.. now i got it.. but i have one question when i extract data from sql script.. how can i make sure.. only data are copied and there is no garbage at the end of the file

Comment: @jack: You need to post that as a separate question with more details.